# Why are all of my text mesh pro (tmp) the same color on my Unity canvas

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have been working on a project in Unity. It's a 3D project and I have a 2D canvas. I have been going through and making several buttons with Text Mess Pro (TMP) on them. I have been changing the color of the text by adjusting the Color Gradient in the Inspector. But when I tried to changed one of them the other day, it got stuck on Black. I don't remember what I did to cause this and I didn't realize it at the time, but it also changed the text on all of my buttons to black.

As I've been looking for a solution (and through previous experimentation of my own) I have learned that changing the color gradient can affect other TMP's that share that gradient, but I can't figure out how to get any of the text colors to change now.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

(My project is in Unity 2019.2.6f1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In TMP you have Vertex color which will change the color of the text instance you are working on and you have Material Color, that will change all the TMP text colors that use the same Material (Usually all of the same font). I have attached an image of the two color options. Are you sure you are changing the correct one.

[image: Different Color Options]

Comment: Ok, it looks like you are onto something for me. It looks like I must have changed my Material Color to black. I have tried changing it to white, transparent, and a few other colors. This now allows me to change the color of my buttons' text again, but they don't quite look the same as they used to. Do you know how to get the Material Color back to its default?

Comment: The TextMeshPro material has a lot of settings and if you changed more than just the color, it will look different. You can either play around with all material settings, to see what works for you and what looks good or if you want the default look, you can always "restore" it to original state by going to "Window" => "TextMeshPro" =>" Font Asset Creator", select the font you want "restored" and click "Generate Font Atlas" this will create new atlas and new default material. Then you just have to select it in the Editor.